# How to create Block Storage From Snapshot In SoftLayer Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I am here trying to create Block Storage using existing Black Storage Snapshot, but I am unable to find API Document related to this. if anyone knows how to create Block Storage from Snapshot in Softlayer. Please help me, or share related Document. it will greatly help full for me.

Comment: This question was already answered in the following forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610081/how-to-create-duplicate-block-storage-from-snapshot-using-softlayer-rest-api