# How to create duplicate block storage from snapshot using Softlayer rest api

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I have created snapshot but unable to create block storage from snapshot. We cant find any Api document. Anyone help me on this request

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following slcli command to order a duplicate volume:

```
slcli block volume-duplicate --origin-snapshot-id 11111 --billing monthly 22222
```

Replace 11111 for your snapshot id and 22222 for your volume id.

To get the list of the snapshot ids for your volume you can use the following command:

```
slcli block snapshot-list 1234
```

Replace 1234 for your volume id.

You can order a duplicate volume through rest call too see the below example:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

Body: Json

```
{"parameters": [{
"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
"packageId": 759,
"location":449600,
"quantity": 1,
"prices": [ 
        { "id": 225129,
          "item": {
              "id": 13215,
              "description": "Storage space for 2 IOPS per GB"
          }},
        { "id": 192043,
          "item": {
              "id": 5938,
              "description": "0.25 IOPS per GB"
          }},            
        {"id": 192473,
        "item": {
              "id": 5130,
              "description": "20 GB Storage Space"
          }}, 
        {"id":189433,
         "item": {
              "id": 9571,
              "description": "Storage as a Service"
          }},
        {"id":189443,
         "item": {
              "id": 5944,
              "description": "Block Storage"
          }}],
"useHourlyPricing": false,
"duplicateOriginSnapshotId": 11111,
"duplicateOriginVolumeId": 22222,
"osFormatType": {  
        "id":12,
        "keyName":"LINUX"
        },
"volumeSize": 16000
}
]}
```

Replace 11111 for your snapshot id and 22222 for your volume id.